# Golang: database/sql. Manejo de errores

Tags: sql, go

He buscando documentación sobre el manejo de errores del paquete database/sql y me resulta confuso cierto patrón bastante repetitivo en Internet.

Suponiendo el siguiente código:

```
func (s *Service) ReadAll() ([]Entity, error) {
    rows, err := s.db.Query("SELECT id, name FROM table")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    entities := make([]Entity, 0)
    for rows.Next() {
        e := new(Entity)
        if err := rows.Scan(&e.ID, &e.Name); err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        entities = append(entities, *e)
    }

    if err = rows.Err(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return entities, nil
}
```

**Primera pregunta:** ¿Es necesario el control *err = rows.Err()*?.
Según entiendo *rows.Err()* retorna error si algo falló en la iteración pero eso ya está previsto con *err = rows.Scan(...)*.

**Segunda pregunta:** ¿Es necesario la linea *defer rows.Close()*?.
Sabiendo que no hay interrupción en la iteración (ningún *brake*) y que el objeto *sql.Rows* se cierra automáticamente ya sea porque llegó al final o porque *rows.Scan(..)* retornó error, ¿Cuál es el objetivo de esa linea?.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

La primera es una buena pregunta, para ser honesto la documentacion es confusa en este punto. Pero lo que dice en `Next()` puede ayudar a clarificar las cosas un poco:

```
// Next prepares the next result row for reading with the Scan method. It
// returns true on success, or false if there is no next result row or an error
// happened while preparing it. Err should be consulted to distinguish between
// the two cases.
```

Lee la ultima oracion.

La segunda, `defer rows.Close()` asegura que no tengas un memory leak, en el peor caso que es un error cuando iteras y haces ese `return nil, err`, ademas es idempotente.

Ahora otra cosa mas que debes de tener en cuenta: `rows.Close()` retorna un error.

[Este Github issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/24329) puede servirte tambien.